# How to get the next Sequence number in Sql Server Express using Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, sql-server-2012

Now that Sql Server 2012 (including SQL Server Express 2012) has `SEQUENCE` feature just like Oracle as explained [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sreekarm/archive/2011/04/18/sequences-in-sql-server.aspx), [here](http://sqljunkieshare.com/2011/12/11/sequences-in-sql-server-2012-implementingmanaging-performance/), and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878058.aspx).

I can get the next `sequence` like so, `SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR SeqName`

But how do I do that from my code using Entity Framework 5?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I got it working using `SqlQuery` like so..

```
int sequence = context.Database.SqlQuery<int>("SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR MySequenceName").FirstOrDefault();
```