# How to use a Sequence which is not bound to a specific table with Entity Framework code-first?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, sequence

I want to have a sequence in my database which is not bound to a specific column or table. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27077948/4961688):

```
public int GetNextSequenceValue()
{
    var rawQuery = Database.SqlQuery<int>("SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.TestSequence;");
    var task = rawQuery.SingleAsync();
    int nextVal = task.Result;

    return nextVal;
}
```

This seems to be exactly what I want, however I'm using code-first and I don't see a way to create the sequence in the first place.

So how do I create a sequence with code-first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself. Just execute this on database creation:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("CREATE SEQUENCE TestSequence AS int START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;");
```