# Insert with linq and SQL Server sequence

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, sql-server-2014

I am using a SQL Server sequence. When I tried to insert values into the database, I used the property `storedGeneratedPattern` for the `Id` column, 
I tried it with `Identity` but I get this error

> (Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected
>   number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since
>   entities were loaded)

And it tried to insert 0 to the ID column and if is there is no id with the value of 0 it insert the 0.

This error appears just when there is an id with 0, and it does not take the next sequence

I tried the `storedGeneratedPattern` with `computed`, but then I get this error

> (Modifications to tables where a primary key column has property
>   'StoreGeneratedPattern' set to 'Computed' are not supported. Use
>   'Identity' pattern instead. Key column: 'WarehouseID'. Table:
>   'Erp_TestModel.Store.Warehouse)

the problem with the insert that it automatically insert 0 to the id column and not using the next value of the sequence , and if no id with the value of 0 in insert the row with 0 in the id
it deals with the sequence as it is not exists

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get next value of SQL Server sequence in Entity Framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27077461/how-to-get-next-value-of-sql-server-sequence-in-entity-framework)

Comment: do I have to select the next value from the sequence then insert it again ??