# Using LINQ to insert data into a table that uses a sequence as primary key generator

Tags: c#, .net, t-sql, linq-to-sql

I have a table which generates its primary key from a sequence (that just counts up from 0):

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[testTable](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [a] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_testTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC))

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblTestTable] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_tblTestTable_id]  DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR [seq_PK_tblTestTable]) FOR [id]
```

I've used Visual Studio's O/R Designer to create the mapping files for the table; the `id` field is defined as:

```cs
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_id", DbType="Int NOT NULL", IsPrimaryKey=true)]
public int id {…}
```

and now I'm trying to insert data via LINQ.

```cs
var testTableRecord = new testTable()
{
    a = 1,
};
db.Connection.Open();
db.testTables.InsertOnSubmit(testTableRecord);
db.SubmitChanges();
Console.WriteLine($"id: {testTableRecord.id}");
```

The problem I'm encountering is, that LINQ seems unable to handle the id generation via sequence as it sets the `id` implicitly to 0 when inserting.

- When I set the `id` to `CanBeNull`, the insert fails because it tries to insert NULL into a non-nullable field.
- When I set the `id` to `IsDbGenerated`, the insert works but it expects an `IDENTITY` field and tries to load the generated id with `SELECT CONVERT(Int,SCOPE_IDENTITY()) AS [value]',N'@p0 int',@p0=1` and than sets the `id` in the object to null because `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` returns `null`…
- I've been thinking about just using `IsDbGenerated`, destroying the LINQ object and querying the DB for the `id`, but I don't have anything unique to search for.

Unfortunately changing the id creation mechanism to IDENTITY is not an option.

Do I have to [explicitly query the DB for the next sequence value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27077461/how-to-get-next-value-of-sql-server-sequence-in-entity-framework) and set the id manually?

Whats the best way to handle these inserts via LINQ?

PS: I need the id because I have to insert more data that uses the id as FK.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at solutions from the raw sql perspective:

1.

```sql
INSERT INTO [dbo].[testTable] VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR [dbo].[seq_PK_tblTestTable], 1)
```

Simply can't be done in LINQ to SQL as far as I can tell

2.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[testTable] (a) VALUES (1)
```

This can be achieved in LINQ to SQL by excluding the id property from the `testTable` entity.

If you need to retrieve ids from the table, you could create separate entities for inserting and querying:

```
public class testTableInsert {
    [ColumnAttribute(...)]
    public int a
}

public class testTableResult {
    [ColumnAttribute(...)]
    public int id

    [ColumnAttribute(...)]
    public int a
}
```

3.

```sql
DECLARE @nextId INT;
SELECT @nextId = NEXT VALUE FOR [dbo].[seq_PK_tblTestTable];  
INSERT INTO [dbo].[testTable] VALUES (@nextId, 1)
```

As you mentioned, this can be essentially achieved by manually requesting the next id before each insert. If you go this route there are multiple ways to achieve it in your code, you can consider stored procedures or use the LINQ data context to manually execute the sql to retrieve the next sequence value.

Here's a code sample demonstrating how to extend the generated DataContext using partial methods.

```
public partial class MyDataContext : System.Data.Linq.DataContext
{
    partial void InsertTestTable(TestTable instance)
    {

        using (var cmd = Connection.CreateCommand()) 
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR [dbo].[seq_PK_TestTable] as NextId";
            cmd.Transaction = Transaction;
            int nextId = (int) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            instance.id = nextId;

            ExecuteDynamicInsert(instance);
        }         
    }
}
```

Once the above is implemented, you can safely insert entities like this, and they will generate the correct sequence id.

```
TestTable entity = new TestTable { a = 2 };
dataContext.TestTables.InsertOnSubmit(entity);
dataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: Method 3 looks interesting; do you know of a way to call the key generation method automatically on submit? It feels quite to error prone without it…

Comment: @Beat added sample in the answer

Comment: on second thought: method 3 seems to be the road to hell! see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54511913/error-duplicatekeyexception-when-setting-the-id-manually-on-insert

Answer (score 2):

Your only hope is a pretty profound refactoring and use a [stored procedure to insert records](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/linq-to-sql-part-7-updating-our-database-using-stored-procedures). The stored procedure can be mapped to the class's `Insert` method in the data context designer.

Using your table definition, the stored is nothing but this:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertTestTable
(
    @id int OUTPUT,
    @a AS int
)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT dbo.testTable (a) VALUES (@a);

    SET @id = (SELECT CONVERT(int, current_value) 
        FROM sys.sequences WHERE name = 'seq_PK_tblTestTable')
END
```

You can import this stored procedure into the context by dragging it from the Sql Object Explorer onto the designer surface, which will then look like this:

[image: dbml designer]

The next step is to click the `testTable` class and click the ellipses button for the Insert method (which got enabled by adding the stored procedure to the context):

[image: Set Insert method]

And customize it as follows:

[image: Set Insert method dialog]

That's all. Now LINQ-to-SQL will generate a stored procedure call to insert a record, for example:

```sql
declare @p3 int
set @p3=8

declare @p5 int
set @p5=0
exec sp_executesql N'EXEC @RETURN_VALUE = [dbo].[InsertTestTable] @id = @p0 OUTPUT, 
    @a = @p1',N'@p0 int output,@p1 int,@RETURN_VALUE int output',
    @p0=@p3 output,@p1=123,@RETURN_VALUE=@p5 output
select @p3, @p5
```

Of course you may have to wonder how long you're going to hang on to LINQ-to-SQL. Entity Framework Core has sequence support [out of the box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/sequences). And much more.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This may be in many cases the best solution but in my specific situation I'd rather not perform any changes to the DB.